# Function as an argument into another function JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function

I need to get access to arguments of func1 in func2 when i called it as an argument in func2, here is the code with comments:

```
let func1 = (x, y) => x + y;

let func2 = function(func1) {
    /* How can i get access to arguments of func1 here, when i call it like that: func2(func1(1, 2)); */
    return func1;
}

func2(func1(1, 2));
```

Comment: You are not passing the function as argument, you're passing its returned value! The last line is the same as `funct2(3);`!

Comment: You would need to do something like func2(func1, 1, 2) if you want to know the arguments

Comment: I don't believe that you can't do what you want to do the way that you want to do it. Could you be more explicit about your end goals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try passing the arguments from func1 into an object and return the object. It would mean reworking other parts of the app I imagine but it shouldn't be too much work. It would have to be done with a regular function as arrows don't have the arguments. [jsbin of the code running here](https://jsbin.com/labadivapu/edit?html,js,console,output)

```
const func1 = function(x, y) {
  const args = arguments
  return {
    args: args,
    main: x + y,
  }
}

const func2 = function(func1) {
    const otherArguments = func1.args
    console.log(otherArguments)
    return func1.main;
}

func2(func1(1, 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You end up having to wrap `func1` in your own function:

```
let func1 = (x, y) => x + y;

let func2 = function(func1) {
    return (...args) => {
        // args is now the arguments that are being passed to func1
        return func1(...args);
    }
}

// Call it like this:
func2(func1)(1, 2);
```

That should get you what you need, because as ibrahim mentioned in his comment, you're passing its return value. `func2(func1(1, 2))` becomes `func2(3)`.

Comment: This looks better than my answer